# An integral related with the Riemann $\zeta$ function

Tags: integration, riemann-zeta

I have to prove that:
$$
\forall s>1,\qquad\int_0^\infty \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k^s+1)^x+k^s}dx=\zeta(s).
$$

I how do I find the closed form for this sum?

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k^s+1)^x+k^s}
$$

Comment: Swap the order of summation $\int_0^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty =  \sum_{k=1}^\infty  \int_0^\infty$ (why can you do this? Tonelli may help), then compute the integral [$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(a+1)^x + a} = \frac{1}{a}$.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?t=crmtb01&i=Integrate%5B1%2F((a+%2B+1)%5Ex+%2B+a),+%7Bx,+0,+Infinity%7D,+Assumptions+-%3E+a+%3E+0%5D)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to complete Ron Gordon's excellent answer, notice that:
$$ I(a,b)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{e^{x\log a}+b} = \frac{1}{\log a}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dz}{e^z+b}=\frac{1}{\log a}\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{t(t+b)}$$
and:
$$ \int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{t(t+b)}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{du}{1+bu}=\frac{1}{b}\int_{0}^{b}\frac{dv}{1+v}=\frac{\log(1+b)}{b}$$
through the substitutions $x=\frac{z}{\log a}$, $z=\log t$, $t=\frac{1}{u}$ and $u=\frac{v}{b}$. That leads to:
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{dx}{(k^s+1)^x+k^s}=\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{\log(1+k^s)}{k^s \log(1+k^s)} = \zeta(s)$$
as wanted.

Comment: Or $$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{e^{x\log(a)}+b}\,dx=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x\log(a)}}{be^{-x\log(a)}+1}\,dx=-\frac{1}{b\log(a)}\left.\log(1+be^{-x\log(a)}) \right|_0^\infty=\frac{\log(1+b)}{b\log(a)}$$

Comment: @Dr.MV: that is a nice shortcut, thank you, Mark.

Comment: Prego, Jacopo!  Il piacere è tutto mio.

Answer (score 7):

Reverse sum and integral and show that

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{a^x+b} = \frac{\log{(1+b)}}{b \log{a}} $$

Note that $a=1+k^s$ and $b=k^s$.  The logs cancel and you are just left with the sum over $k^{-s}$, which is the stated result.